# ADODB library error in exe launched through php

Tags: php, apache, vb6, webserver

I have a 32 bit executable written in VB6 that uses the ADODB library, this exe is launched by a php script.
If I run the script from the command line (`'php.exe /f script.php'`) everything works, but when the same script is launched from the web server (apache 2.4) there is an 'automation error' in the .exe file when try to create `ADODB.Connection`.

Local webserver on Windows 7

It is evident that the problem is not ADODB otherwise it would never work, however I spent many hours working on the Apache and php user permissions, but the evidence shows that the user running istance of php that run the script is always the current one.

At this point I have finished the ideas, if someone has some new ones, I will be grateful

Comment: We don't have enough information.  What error number?  What operation fails?  Are you performing any ADO operations that make use of WinInet, raise a dialog, etc. which would require an interactive user context?

Comment: There are not a error number! I tried also to retrieve objects `ADODB.errors` but it's empty. The error appears when call `ADODB.connection`.
The **same** executable (I wrote it) works for years without problems in standalone.
Unfortunately there are no verifiable parameters, or at least I do not see them

Comment: Where did you get the error string "automation error"? Whatever the source was, it didn't include an error number?

Comment: The error it's in the executable when try to connect to ADODB `Set conn = new ADODB.Connection`. The object is not initialized, so it is not possible to access the internal property `Errors`.

I managed to get around the problem even if I did not understand what caused it
Thanks anyway for your interest

Comment: The error in question would not be in the Errors collection, but instead held within the VB6 Err object.

Comment: Yes, in fact it is the `automation error` I've mentioned in my first post

Comment: By default, all Apache services are registered to run as the system user (the `LocalSystem` account). It is recommended that users create a separate account for running Apache service(s). Continue reading at [Using Apache HTTP Server on Microsoft Windows](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html) docs -- pretty sure you have permissions problem that exhibits in peculiar way.